# 234÷5 is 46.8 - I got 46 but I missed the .8 decimal point out, can you tell me why?

Tags: arithmetic

I got 46 and I couldn't work out how to get the .8 decimal seeing as 5 couldn't go into the 4 and that was the last number, I couldn't make the number bigger because I had nothing to carry, so if 5 couldn't go into 4, I didn't know where to get the .8 decimal. I am very bad at math

Comment: Because $4/5 = 0.8.$

Comment: $\frac{234}{5}=46\frac{4}{5}=46+\color{red}{\frac{4}{5}}=46\color{red}{.8}$.

Comment: This may be clearer if you think of $46.8$ as being $\frac{468}{10}$.

Comment: I'd suggest reading through [these tutorials on Long Division](http://www.wikihow.com/Do-Long-Division) to learn the general idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire point about decimals is to go "past the decimal point" and carry from the infinite number of zeros, past the decimal point.

You can't end up with a remainder and ... then throw that remainder away.

So $234 = 234.0000000000000000000000.......$

$23$ divided by $5$ is $4$ with $3$ remainder.

So $230$ divided by $5$ is going to be $4*10$ with $30$ to be divided later.

So $234\div 5$ is $40$ plus whatever $34 \div 5$ is.

$30\div 5 = 6$ and $34 = 30 + 4$ so $34\div 5$ with be $6$ with $4$ to be divided later.

So $234\div 5 = 46$ plus whatever $4 \div 5$ is.

**NOW** we have to carry from the infinite number of zeros$.

$4 = 40 *\frac 1{10} = 40*.1$.

And $40\div 5 = 8$ so $4\div 5 = (40*\div 5)*.1= 8*.1 = .8$.

So $234 \div = 46.8$.

.... or .....$234 = 20*10 + 30*1 + 40*.1$

And $234\div = (20\div 5)*10 + (30\div 5)*1 + (40 \div 5)*.1 = 40 + 6 + .8 = 46.8$.

Comment: Thank you all, but more so to fleablood you explained it perfectly and I found it relatively easy to follow. :)